# Email a picture after having saved it

Tags: php, email, canvas

I have a canvas which I am saving to the server, what is the best way to  email the picture -attached or embedded - I have just appended some @mail code but i think there should be a more efficient way as I am already transferring the encoded base64 file. I am not sure how to pass on the values of the email and name along with the file, I am a complete beginner with PHP, 
Here is my code:

```
<?php
   $data = $_POST['canvasData'];

//$file = "/path/to/file.png";    $file = "canvases/file.png";
iterator_count(new DirectoryIterator('canvases'));
$file = "canvases/file_" . iterator_count(new DirectoryIterator('canvases')).".png";

$uri =  substr($data,strpos($data,",")+1);
$uri = str_replace(' ','+',$uri);
file_put_contents($file, base64_decode($uri));

echo $file;


$to =   'info@ventoline.co.uk';
$subject =  'test receive a drawn msg from  ventoline www';
$bound_text =   "euhh?";
$bound =    "--".$bound_text."\r\n";
$bound_last =   "--".$bound_text."--\r\n";

$headers =  "From: admin@server.com\r\n";
$headers .=     "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
."Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$bound_text\"";

$message .=     "If you can see this MIME than your client doesn't accept MIME types!\r\n"
.$bound;

$message .=     "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n"
."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n"
."hey my <b>good</b> friend here is a picture of regal beagle\r\n"
.$bound;

$file =     file_get_contents($file);

$message .=     "Content-Type: image/jpg; name=\"regal_004.jpg\"\r\n"
."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
."Content-disposition: attachment; file=\"regal_004.jpg\"\r\n"
."\r\n"
.chunk_split(base64_encode($file))
.$bound_last;

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    echo 'MAIL SENT';
} else {
    echo 'MAIL FAILED';
}
?>
```

It returns 'MAIL SENT', but I haven't received anything yet.

Comment: Solution: Use a php email library, such as swift or phpmailer

Comment: it seems to be working, yakes about an hour to come through:/
thanks for the comments, whats an RFC?